# How to make a parent invisible with Ajax in Wicket?

Tags: wicket

```
    Last cause: The component(s) below failed to render. Possible reasons could be that:
    1) you have added a component in code but forgot to reference it in the markup (thus the component will never be rendered),
    2) if your components were added in a parent container then make sure the markup for the child container includes them in <wicket:extend>.

1. [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = child, page = com.test.TestPage, path = parent:child, type = org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainer, isVisible = true, isVersioned = true]]
```

I'm trying to hava a WebMarkupContainer that can be made invisible by clicking their child, which is also a WebMarkupContainer. I get the exception above and I don't understand what to change to make it work.

My code is the following:

```
@MountPath("test")
public class TestPage extends WebPage {


    public TestPage(PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);

        IModel<Boolean> isVisible = Model.of(false);

        WebMarkupContainer parent = new WebMarkupContainer("parent"){
            @Override
            public boolean isVisible() {
                return !isVisible.getObject();
            }
        };
        parent.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(parent);

        WebMarkupContainer child = new WebMarkupContainer("child");
        child.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("click") {
            @Override
            protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                isVisible.setObject(true);
                target.add(parent);
            }

        });
        parent.add(child);
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<wicket:extend>

    <div wicket:id="parent"
         style="height: 300px; width: 100%;  background-color: mediumvioletred; padding: 10px; margin: 70px;">

            <div wicket:id="child"
                 style="height: 200px; width: 200px; color: cadetblue; background-color: rebeccapurple">
                click me
            </div>

    </div>

</wicket:extend>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what's going on with the isVisible override, but it's causing the odd behavior.
Try this instead:

```
@Override
protected void onConfigure() {
    super.onConfigure();
            
    setVisible(isVisible.getObject());
}
```

This will be called only once per lifecycle, while isVisible is called multiple times.

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression that using setVisible() was the best way to go, but digging into the documentation revealed a note at the end of https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/guide/9.x/single.html#_implement_visibilities_of_components_correctly that lead to this: https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@wicket.apache.org/msg07124.html

Comment: I dug a little deeper, this is a rather new recommendation which becomes visible if you compare https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/guide/9.x/single.html#_hiding_or_disabling_a_component and https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_hiding_or_disabling_a_component. isVisible() used to be recommended, now it's not anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `<wicket:extend>` from the HTML! Your page does not extend from another page that uses `<wicket:child/>`.

Extra notes:

It is not very clear what you want to do. You say `want to make visible` but it starts as visible and click on the child will make it `invisible` due to the negation in

```
public boolean isVisible() {
    return !isVisible.getObject();
}
```

Does it fail to render the initial page or after the Ajax click ?

**Important**: when changing visibility with Ajax always use `parent.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);` instead of `parent.setOutputMarkupId(true);` because otherwise you won't be able to make it visible again - there won't be an HTML DOM element to be replaced with the given `id`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using my own implementation of WebPage which uses <wicket:child> so I need <wicket:extend>. It was a typo in the text to say visible, I meant invisible like the title and code say. The render fails after clicking the link. When I use the WebPage from wicket I can't click at all and nothing happens.